# Azure DataFactory - Can we ordered CopyData source before ingestion

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a case where I need to ingest CSV files into CosmosDb.
So I have one DataSets to process the CSV, and another to prepare CosmosDb schema.

In the pipeline, I have a CopyData task mapping from CSV and then writing in Cosmos.
In the CopyData Source parameter, I specify an Azure Blob Storage where CSV are stored.

Until now, there was no problem.
Thing is, I now need to find a way to ensure that blobs are ingested like an alphabeticaly ordered files array (based on fileName).

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to sort by fileNames in ADF.

One way to achieve:

Save all your fileNames in a csv file, then use Sort activity in Data Flow and overwrite this file. Finally, use Lookup and For Each activity to copy blobs to Cosmos DB.

Another way:

Pass childItems of Get Metadata activity's output to Azure Function. Then sort fileNames in Azure Function. Finally, loop output of Function by For Each activity and copy to Cosmos DB.

Comment: Actually, the need to sort on fileName hide the simple need to first ingest the first blob stored. This is the real need. Currently, without any additional process it doesn't seems to ingest first the first blob uploaded. I think your both way would work, I would go for "second way" because I can't use DataFlow (not available in China).
Do we just know how ADF retrieve data from storage Account ? Based on which order ?

Comment: So your need is to get the blob which earliest uploaded among one folder?